VSCode Explorer doesn't open any folders when connected to a remote server
So basically, whenever I connect to my remote server (using ssh), the explorer in vscode has no folder opened. There's a "Open Folder" button there, which I have to use to open the cwd, but the issue is this requires me to re-authenticate my connection to the remote server, and considering that our organization uses DUO Mobile, it really is a pain in the back
